# HTML Agility Pack not behaving as expected

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse this HTML page here with HTML Agility Pack, but I cannot seem to get it to work as expected.

This is my page (shortened):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de-ch" xml:lang="de-ch">
<head>
</head>
<body id="Adressservices">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-544">
            <table class="full">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="first" scope="col" style="width: 18%;">Type</th>
                        <th class="col" style="width: 20%;">Name</th>
                        <th class="col">Date</th>
                        <th class="col" style="text-align: right; width: 10%;">Size</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first">Change</td>
                        <td><a href="/download?file=5210044">somefile01.zip</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 5%;"><b class="filesize">2012-03-01</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><b class="filesize">881.00</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first">Change</td>
                        <td><a href="/download?file=7610042">somefile02.zip</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 5%;"><b class="filesize">2012-02-01</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><b class="filesize">1400.00</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>.....</tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The real page has quite a few more `<tr>....</tr>` rows in that table.

I was able to download the page just fine with HTML Agility Pack using this code snippet:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument archiveDoc = web.Load(_archiveUrl);
var tables = archiveDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
```

So I get a handle on my `<table>` element, works just fine.

Now I was trying to get the **first** `<tr>` element from within that table, and I tried this:

```
HtmlNode node = tables[0];
var allTRNodes = node.SelectNodes("tbody/tr");
var firstTR = allTRNodes[0];
```

Here, I'm not getting the n `<tr>` nodes as expected - but just two. And the first of those doesn't contain a list of y child nodes of type `<td>` either ...

Then I tried Linq-to-"HTML":

```
HtmlNode node = tables[0];
var firstTR = node.Element("tbody").Element("tr");
```

but again: I'm not getting the first `<tr>` node containing a list of y child nodes of type `<td>` either ...

Trying to get the list of all `<td>` nodes inside the first `<tr>` also didn't work quite as expected:

```
HtmlNode node = tables[0];
var allTDNodes = node.SelectNodes("tbody/tr/td");
var firstTD = allTDNodes[0];
```

instead of the y `<td>` nodes expected, I'm getting just three child nodes - two of the `#text`, the last one of type `<td>` - why??

Seems like HTML Agility Pack is misinterpreting the list of `<td>` nodes as nested nodes......

Any ideas? Thoughts? Hints how to solve this?

Comment: It's strange. With your HTML example `allTRNodes` has 3 `tr` nodes(the last one with ...); `allTDNodes` has 8 `td` nodes on my side ( HtmlAgilityPack v2.0.50727). One more assumption - maybe your HTML code which you didn't include in the example is broken?

Comment: Same here, with latest stable download of HAP.

Comment: @Alex: yes, the `allTDNodes` has over 60 elements in my "real" sample - it's just confusing - I was assuming that if I start from a given `trNode` I would get all the **child nodes** of that node - not **all** nodes from the whole document!

Comment: @marc_s: This is a well known issue. After you select the table, it is a mistake to do node.SelectNodes("tbody/tr") because it will search from the root of the doc all over again, regardless what you had selected before. If you want to refer the current "selected" node then use "." for example node.SelectNodes("./tbody/tr")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use descendant as in this example:

```
var linkNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingle("//div[@id=\"content-wrapper\"]/dl/dd");
var hrefNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::a");
```

Something I don't agree with HtmlAgility pack that node.SelectNode* call traversing dom from the top and not from the current *node*.

Here's adopted sample for your case

```
// table 
var tableNode = docNode.SelectSingleNode("//table"); 
// first tr
var trNode = tableNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::tr"); 

// you can also try, but it's overkill
var trNode1 = tableNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::tr[0]"); 

// then your td
var tdNode = trNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::td");
```

Comment: I just had a similar issue with node.selectNode traversing the entire document. I hope that gets changed in the future.

Comment: Dat wud be bad idea as every AgilityPack user will have to change the code to adopt to the new behaviour... I think software becomes legacy as soon as it's shipped if not before...